# Select a text and perform a click action

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to select some text and perform a click action - like in Winword where we click `Bold` after selecting some text...

I have to select the text and click on the `<B>` bold icon in the `textarea`.

Any idea on how to do this using Selenium/Webdriver?

Comment: How about sending Ctrl+B keys using driver.sendKeys()?

Comment: AJ tnx for response But followig are my questions...1-the <B> button is on the browser iframe itself. Not from Keyboard. 2-And u did not mention how to select a text in selenium/webdriver.

Comment: Here is the answer for qn 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516383/how-to-manipulate-user-selected-text-using-webdriver

Answer (score 9):

In Java, [The Advanced User Interactions API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) has your answer.

```
// the element containing the text
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("text"));
// assuming driver is a well behaving WebDriver
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
// and some variation of this:
actions.moveToElement(element, 10, 5)
    .clickAndHold()
    .moveByOffset(30, 0)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `Action` `builder` and played with `offset`. It worked for me.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(wblmt,3,3).click().keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(wblmt,200, 0).click().keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it did not work. Here are the codes:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.vn");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Google.com.vn')]"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(text, 10, 5).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(30, 0).release().perform();
```

I switched to JavascriptExecutor and it worked:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.vn");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Google.com.vn')]"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: blue;');", text);
```

Answer (score 0):

driver.navigate().to("https://leafground.com/input.xhtml");
WebElement cls= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class="ql-editor ql-blank"]"));
cls.sendKeys("this is rakshika " + Keys.CONTROL + "a");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class="ql-italic"]\r\n")).click();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).