# How select text programmatically in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I write test in selenium. I have span element. When user select text in this span and press ctrl+c, in this page will popup windows. But how can I select this text programmatically?
I tried two way: use selenium call webElement.Click() 3 times. Because I know, if three times click by span, then will select all text in this span. But it throw exception, that System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point 
Also I tried programmatically via c# move and click cursor. But problem is, that in virtual machine in test agent, the cursor doesn't move.
So Can you help me select text in span?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978081/select-a-text-and-perform-a-click-action

Answer (score 2):

Why make the task way more complicated than it should be?  You can make this simpler by doing:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("theSpanElementId")).getText();
// now you have the text from the <span> element stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#,

```
string spanText = driver.findElement(By.Id("SomeElementId")).Text;
```